# Why can I not access any of the options when using dconf-editor?

Tags: dconf

I recently installed [dconf editor](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/dconf-tools/) from the software centre. But when I launch it I am unable to navigate any of the options, clicking any of the entries in the tree on the left does not expand the menus.

Am I missing something really obvious?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

yes you are missing something really obvious. You have to click on the arrows, to get to the sub items:

[image]

Comment: I think I should probably hand back all my reputation on this site! Though in fairness it seems a poor design decision that double clicking doesn't expand the menus you have to click the small arrow, not good for accessability.

Comment: yes, that is a poor design decision. And yes, I had that problem too :-)