# dconf-editor gui doesn't show anything

Tags: dconf

I'm having trouble using dconf-editor. On startup I get the following warning twice:

```
** (dconf-editor:4690): WARNING **: dconf-schema.vala:330: Unknown property on <schema>, extends.
```

The gui comes up but none of the fields ( apps, ca, com, desktop, org, system ) are expandable. I found that the environmental variable `DCONF_PROFILE` wasn't set. I set the variable to :

```
$ export DCONF_PROFILE=/etc/dconf/profile/ibus
$ printenv DCONF_PROFILE
/etc/dconf/profile/ibus

$ cat /etc/dconf/profile/ibus
user-db:user
system-db:ibus
```

when I bring up `dconf-editor` again, I have the same results.
Anyone know what I'm doing wrong and how to correct it?

Answer (score 2):

I hope on opening it, you can see items like apps, ca, com, desktop etc. Clicking on them won't do anything. Click on the arrow next to them to load the submenu. This really pissed me off too.

[click here for a similar question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/137777/why-can-i-not-access-any-of-the-options-when-using-dconf-editor/137779#137779)